# Not able to get Exception message from SOAP call using service reference .net

Tags: c#, .net, service-reference, faultexception, estes-express-api

I am using service reference in .NET to call a third party carrier API i.e. ESTES. you can find the wsdl [here](http://www.estes-express.com/bol/services/BolService?wsdl). now whenever I call it from the code and there are some errors it just throws a FaultException and exception message as GeneralErrorMsg or SchemavalidationError with no meaningful messages. I do get the meaningful messages when I run it in SOAP UI tool but not from .Net code.

Following are some link of images of exception. FYI innerexception is null

[Exception Stack Trace Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/worbe.png)

[Exception Data Property Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ELHR.png)

Below is the response that I get, when I run the API using SOAPUI. FYI this is third party API and not ours I am just calling their API

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>GeneralErrorMsg</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <bol:generalError xmlns:bol="http://ws.estesexpress.com/bol">
               <bol:error>
                  <bol:code>BOL0193</bol:code>
                  <bol:message>We cannot automatically assign a PRO number if the shipping address is not serviced       directly by Estes.  Please   uncheck the "Assign PRO #" box.  Questions?  Feel free to call your &lt;a href="/WebApp/TerminalList/"> local terminal&lt;/a>.</bol:message>
               </bol:error>
               <bol:error>
                  <bol:code>BOL0101</bol:code>
                  <bol:message>Invalid state/zip combination</bol:message>
               </bol:error>
            </bol:generalError>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please help me guys its really giving me hard time.

Comment: could you resolve the issue? I have the same exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding service behavior in web.config file where your service is hosted

```
<behavior name="faultBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
</behavior>
```

But this has some other down side in terms of security.

Comment: I appreciate you help Rahul. but its not our service its third party. I have added the response too that I get from the API. Can you look at it and help me.
Thanks you so much again

Comment: hmm, may i know "**I do get the meaningful messages when I run it in SOAP UI tool **" exact message you are getting ?

Comment: example this is coming from the API response when I run it in SOAP UI:
We cannot automatically assign a PRO number if the shipping address is not serviced       directly by Estes.  Please   uncheck the "Assign PRO #" box.  Questions?  Feel free to call your &lt;a href="/WebApp/TerminalList/"> local terminal&lt;/a>

This is a meaningful message. not schemaValidationError or GeneralErroMessage.

Comment: Ideally FaultException<T> detail property should have captured message. is it httpbinding ? I mean is there a way to capture http response (say using developer tool) to see exact SOAP body before its gets deserialized at client end

Comment: are you sure request is exactly same when you invoke from tool and .Net code ?

Comment: yes request is exactly same. Its just that when real user put some wrong values then I get these messages. I have tried FaultException<T> but nothing there too. When I run the same request in SOAP UI it give me the proper messages.

Comment: i still strongly feel that error you getting while calling service using .net code is because of different reason (what i mean to say is that your request is not even reached to point responsible for throwing exception with details when not using soap ui tool)

Comment: @KhurramSyed : any luck ? did you managed to capture response when using .net code (the way you did from UI tool and posted as part of original question)

Comment: nope still no luck. I know that why errors are coming. I know what I am sending wrong but the only problem is that user needs to see those message when calling this API. which they are not.

Comment: @KhurramSyed : I think the whole point here is why you see error while consuming service from UI tool and not when using .Net Code.